# Lowercase sentences in lists in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have a pandas data frame like below. I want to convert all the text into lowercase. How can I do this in python?

> Sample of data frame

```
[Nah I don't think he goes to usf, he lives around here though]                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

[Even my brother is not like to speak with me., They treat me like aids patent.]                                                                                                                                                                                                      

[I HAVE A DATE ON SUNDAY WITH WILL!, !]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

[As per your request 'Melle Melle (Oru Minnaminunginte Nurungu Vettam)' has been set as your callertune for all Callers., Press *9 to copy your friends Callertune]                                                                                                                      

[WINNER!!, As a valued network customer you have been selected to receivea £900 prize reward!, To claim call 09061701461., Claim code KL341., Valid 12 hours only.]
```

> What I tried

```
def toLowercase(fullCorpus):
   lowerCased = [sentences.lower()for sentences in fullCorpus['sentTokenized']]
   return lowerCased
```

> I get this error

```
lowerCased = [sentences.lower()for sentences in fullCorpus['sentTokenized']]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can also make it a `string`, use `str.lower` and get back to lists.

```
import ast
df.sentTokenized.astype(str).str.lower().transform(ast.literal_eval)
```

Comment: This is going to save me a lot of time

Answer (score 5):

It is easy:

```
df.applymap(str.lower)
```

or

```
df['col'].apply(str.lower)
df['col'].map(str.lower)
```

---

Okay, you have lists in rows. Then:

```
df['col'].map(lambda x: list(map(str.lower, x)))
```

Comment: I get these errors - TypeError: ("descriptor 'lower' requires a 'str' object but received a 'list'", 'occurred at index sentTokenized'),  TypeError: descriptor 'lower' requires a 'str' object but received a 'list'

Comment: @Kabilesh See upd.

Comment: Thank you. Find usefull with colab

Comment: How to do this, if there are NaNs in the list

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `apply` and `map`:

```
def toLowercase(fullCorpus):
   lowerCased = fullCorpus['sentTokenized'].apply(lambda row:list(map(str.lower, row)))
   return lowerCased
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a nice way to do it with [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.char.lower.html#numpy.char.lower):

```py
fullCorpus['sentTokenized'] = [np.char.lower(x) for x in fullCorpus['sentTokenized']]
```